# Calling a function within req,res

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following code snippet in my routes:

```
router.get("/home", (req,res) =>{
        var message = req.session.user1;
        res.render("home", {data: message});
    })
```

In my taskController.js, I have a function that I would query data using Sequelize that should also be passed to home. How can I insert the function in the snippet above?

My initial idea was

```
 router.get("/home", (req,res) =>{
            Some query here stored in var task
            var message = req.session.user1;
            res.render("home", {data: message, dataTwo: task});
        })
```

But this only applies if I do the usual MySql query within the route. But I'm currently using Sequelize (which is in my taskController.js) to do the querying for me. So my option is to call that function in that controller and use it in the router.get above but I'm not quite sure on how to incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to asynchronously fetch the `task` from your controller. Require your controller, then make the function for the route `async (req, res)`, and call the function on your controller that returns the `task` using `await`. The function in your controller should also be `async` and either return the sequelize Promise directly, or after modifying the data as needed.

```js
// import your controller
const controller = require('./controllers/controller');

// make the function async
router.get("/home", async (req, res) => {
  // await the result of a function that is async (returns a promise)
  const task = await controller.getTask(maybeSomeId);
  const message = req.session.user1;
  res.render("home", {data: message, dataTwo: task});
});

// you can add error handling like this
router.get("/home2", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    // await the result of a function that is async (returns a promise)
    const task = await controller.getTask(maybeSomeId);
    const message = req.session.user1;
    return res.render("home", {data: message, dataTwo: task});
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: actually my getTask function is done like this exports.displayHome = async (req, res) so it can be called by router.get("/home", controller.getTask); but I want it to happen in the router.get("/home", (req,res) => ... How?